# php preg_match() to validate input

Tags: php

I would like to use the preg_match() to validate a textfield, that clients can later on insert it to the database.
However there is one thing that I don't understand. How would the preg_match() look if I want the client to enter eight numbers and then a dash (-) and four numbers. **That input must match exactly**

**Therefore**

N = number

Input:
NNNNNNNN-NNNN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you want is this:

```
/^\d{8}-\d{4}$/
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iJ6pI0/2)

This says: match the start of the string (`^`), exactly 8 digits (`\d{8}`), a hyphen (`-`), exactly 4 digits (`\d{4}`), and then the end of the string (`$`).

So, the `preg_match` looks like this:

```
preg_match('/^\\d{8}-\\d{4}$/', $theData);
```